# Console.ReadKey() doesn't catch certain combination [shift+up]

Tags: c#, console

This seems to be an easy case but for some reason, the `Console.ReadKey()` doesn't work with arrows in console when you use the shift modifier. It looks like Microsoft decided to override it to do selection.

I was wondering if it's possible to change that default behavior for the `ReadKey()`? I've read the documentation, but other than the intercept boolean, it seems non-existant. No mention of it whatsoever.

Also, I've looked at some Win32 function like `GetKeyState`, but it would mean that I wouldn't be able to mix `ReadKey()` with it since I would need to do some polling vs thread blocking.

So, should I just make an old Win32 Loop and handle all the messages manually? Or is there a simpler solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe look at the [KeyBoard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Perhaps you could set up an event handler to capture the keystrokes you are missing.

Comment: @JohnWu It's referencing the PresentationCore.dll. It might work but it seems a littlebit overkill to include WPF references. If I can't find anything, I might try.

Comment: After a couple of hours, I found something interesting, but so complicated: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=inputsimulator

Comment: A minimal example would be `Console.ReadKey(true);` in the main.

Comment: @JohnWu Thanks for your help, I was able to find the issue using your idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for many hours, I stumble on this github project:

https://github.com/michaelnoonan/inputsimulator

After installing it and started to fiddle with it, I found out that the input was finally working [shift+left]. But the selection was still appearing. I started to search for disable selection in console. I didn't find anything in the API. But I remembered that my console window have by default the "Quick Edit" flag.

So, After looking at the other flags, I found out 2 interesting flags in the Text Selection Group. By un-checking those 2 flags, the window key override was removed and the `ReadKey` could work normally.